# How do you filter data by category using an action and reducer in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, object, redux

I am building a filter, where users are able to filter data by which type of category they would like, for example, restaurants, bars, cafes, etc. The user uses the filter, by selecting whether the category is true of false (i.e. whether that specific category is displayed or not), which is then sent to my action and reducer. How would you set the reducer to filter the data, so only the categories which are true show up?

This is my filter.js file (with shop and food either being true or false):

```
onButtonPress() {
    const { shop, food } 
    = this.state;

this.props.filterRecommendations({ shop, food });
```

This is my action.js file:

```
export const filterRecommendations = ({ shop, food}) => {
    return {
        type: FILTER_RECOMMENDATIONS_BY_TYPE,
        payload: { shop, food }
    };
};
```

This is my reducer.js file:

```
export const reducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
    case FILTER_RECOMMENDATIONS_BY_TYPE:
        return {
            ...state,
                myRecommendations: state.myRecommendations.filter(
            item => item.type === action.payload
            )
        };
};
```

Data looks like this:

```
myRecommendations: [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'Yes Food',
      type: 'food'
    },
            {
      id: '2',
      name: 'Yes Shop',
      type: 'shop'
    },
]
```

What results above is just all the data clearing.

Comment: You should not be using reducers to get values. Reducers are useful to update the state. Instead use selectors.

Comment: Can you show / link to a good example? I have never used selectors...

Comment: https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect. Hopefully it will help you.

Comment: Also see redux's docs, they are pretty good for explaining how and why [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data)

Comment: @smashed-potatoes why did you remove your answer?

Comment: @kingloui I overcomplicated the solution - HiRenS filtering along with using selectors should get you where you need to go. I can clean it up and bring it back if you are interested though.

Comment: @smashed-potatoes yeah I would appreciate that! Thanks :)

Comment: were you able to help further with this @smashed-potatoes?

Answer (score 2):

@Yuvi's suggestion to use a selector is a good idea. It allows you to filter your list without mutating your reducer's state. This is important in your case because with your current approach each time you change your filter you will remove more data from your state i.e.:

1. Select `food` > `myRecommendations` only contains `food` items now
2. Select `shop` > `myRecommendations` is empty because `shop` items were removed above

Redux has documentation outlining how to do this [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data).
Without selectors you would need a way to re-populate your `myRecommendations` state between filter calls.

Using something like `reselect` (see [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect)) will help performance by memoizing the selector, but the underlying concept is to:

1. Keep unfiltered results in your state
2. Store your filter selection as its own state
3. Filter the data where it is needed based on the filter state

i.e.:

**filter.js** - Set the selected filter

```
onButtonPress() {
  const { shop, food } = this.state;
  this.props.setRecommendationsFilter({ shop, food });
}
```

**Wherever you define your action names**

```
const SET_RECOMMENDATIONS_FILTER = 'SET_RECOMMENDATIONS_FILTER';
```

**action.js**

```
export const setRecommendationsFilter = (filter) => {
  return {
    type: SET_RECOMMENDATIONS_FILTER,
    filter,
};
```

**reducer.js** - Store the selected filter without modifying the recommendations data

```
export const reducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_RECOMMENDATIONS_FILTER: {
      return {
        ...state,
        recommendationsFilter: action.filter,
      };
    }
  }
};
```

**Where you use the filtered recommendations** - This is the selector concept

```
// 1. Bring in myRecommendations and recommendationsFilter from redux

// 2. Filter
/**
 * Get a filtered list of items, where the filter that matches
 * the recommendation 'type' is set to 'true'
 */
const filteredRecommendations = myRecommendations.filter(
  (item) => recommendationsFilter[item.type]
);

// 3. Now use filteredRecommendations as you would have used myRecommendations
```

When using something like reselect, you would put the logic that creates `filteredRecommendations` along with the logic to get the data you need from redux in a selector and then use that selector in your `mapStateToProps` (as described [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data#connecting-a-selector-to-the-redux-store)).

Answer (score 1):

You can access the object keys by filtering the data:

`state.myRecommendations.filter(item => action.payload[item.type])`

Answer (score 0):

This might be work for you

On button click you can pass the array for all filters

```
onButtonPress() {
    const { shop, food } 
    = this.state;

this.props.filterRecommendations([shop, food ]);
```

```
export const filterRecommendations = (recommendationList ) => {
    return {
        type: FILTER_RECOMMENDATIONS_BY_TYPE,
        payload: recommendationList
    };
};
```

```
export const reducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
    case FILTER_RECOMMENDATIONS_BY_TYPE:
        return {
            ...state,
                myRecommendations: state.myRecommendations.filter(
            item => action.payload.includes(item.type)
            )
        };
};
```